# how to get gmail content with content has been encode

Tags: gmail, imap

When i try to get subject and content email, i alwasy got this content has been encode, example:

subject: Thư cảm ơn

I got this subject has been encode: Th=C6=B0_c=E1=BA=A3m_=C6=A1n?=

so how to decode this content.

Answer (score 0):

That string *looks* like it's supposed to be encoded in the format mandated by [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt), except that it is corrupt: RFC 2047 encoded strings always begin with `=?` end end with `?=`.

Assuming you can get a non-corrupt encoded string, you should expect to see not only the `Subject` but also the display names in `To`, `From`, and other headers to be encoded in this way. You might want to look into using a library that does complete MIME parsing for you. Appropriate available libraries will depend on what language you're using.